# react - force componentDidUpdate() when props are same value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In my component im trying to sync the received props with the current state in order to make it visible from outside (I know this is an anti-pattern, but I haven't figured out another solution to this yet. Im very open to suggestions!).

Anyways, this is what I've got:

```
export class PopupContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: false,
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.props.show === nextProps.show) return true;
    return true;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    // if popup shown, fade it out in 500ms
    if (this.props.show !== prevProps.show)
      this.setState({ show: this.props.show });

    if (this.state.show) {
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({ show: false }), 2000);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Popup {...{ ...this.props, show: this.state.show }} />;
  }
}
```

And in my external component I'm rendering the container :

```
<PopupContainer
          show={this.state.popup.show}
          message={this.state.popup.message}
          level={this.state.popup.level}
        />
```

Now when I initially set `this.state.show` to `true` it works, but every successive assignment which is also `true` without any `false` assignment inbetween doesn't work. How do I force `componentdidUpdate()` to fire anyways even if the props are the same value? `shouldComponentUpdate()` didn't seem to solve the problem.

Thank you!

Edit: I noticed that the `render()` method is only called in the parent element. It seems like as there is no change in properties for the child, react doesn't even bother rerendering the childern which somehow makes sense. But how can I force them to rerender anyways?

Comment: you can do a `this.forceUpdate()` when you need to force the component to rerender , https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: @semuzaboi The thing is it's actually rerendering. Just the `componentDidUpdate()` method is not called.

Comment: that condition in `shouldComponentUpdate` is reduntant as it returns `true` anyway

Comment: @barbsan I know it was just included to demonstrate that it's not resolving the issue.

Comment: @Biko Kießling try this if it works:
In shouldComponentUpdate instead of `this.props.show` to `this.state.show` and `nextProps.show to nextState.show`

Comment: @somsgod doesn't help either. I realized that I was wrong and the child component is not rerendering. Just the parent `render` method is called but as there is no change in props nothing is done inside child.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack, but it works for me.

**In the child class**

Add a property to state in constructor - let's call it `myChildTrigger`, and set it to an empty string:

```
this.state = {
   ...
   myChildTrigger: ''
}
```

then add this to `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if(this.state.myChildTrigger !== this.props.myParentTrigger) {

      // Do what you want here

      this.setState({myChildTrigger: this.props.myParentTrigger});
   }
}
```

**In the parent class**

Add a `myParentTrigger` to state in constructor:

```
this.state = {
   ...
   myParentTrigger: ''
}
```

In the render method, add it as a prop, like this:

```
<ChildClass ... myParentTrigger={this.state.myParentTrigger} />
```

Now you can trigger a call to `componentDidUpdate` to execute whatever is inside the if-statement, just by setting `myParentTrigger` to a new value, like:

```
this.setState({ myParentTrigger: this.state.myParentTrigger + 'a' });
```